# Laravel 5.4 dynamic notification types

Tags: php, laravel-5, notifications, laravel-5.4

I'm designing a mass notification system that requires the user to have the option of sending the notifications via mail, sms or both. I'm using the notification facade and trying to allow for that with something like the `deliverVia()` method that exists in `Illuminate\Notifications\ChannelManager` like so:

```
$notificationType = 'mail';
Notification::send($customers, new MassCommunicationTool($data))->deliverVia($notificationType);
```

This errors out with

```
Call to a member function deliverVia() on null
```

Is anyone familiar with a good solution for this? I know `deliverVia()` does expect a string that is the channel, I've just never seen in combined with the notification facade before. This is obviously not the correct way of calling it, just an example of what I'm trying. That `Notification::send();` returning null is expected behavior.

Comment: well apearantly `Notification::send($customers, new MassCommunicationTool($data))` returns null, your first option is to go find out why that is

Comment: It returns null because it fires the notification and returns null. That's expected behavior. What I'm looking for is how to fire the notification and set the channel at the same time.

Comment: if it's expected behaviour why you even try to access a method on it ;) anyways their doc's would probably help you out see  https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/notifications#using-the-notification-facade basicly you have to extend your notification class with a `via` method and then make your logic on there.

Comment: Alright. Yes, that makes sense. I'll just pass an array of notificationTypes to the notification and set that to a protected property and return in the via method. I just thought there might be a way to call it while firing the notification. Thanks!